# Compute Normalized Gibbs Entropy in Python

Tags: python, pandas, loops, jupyter-notebook, entropy

I am working with a dataset that contains information on teams that have anywhere between 2 and 17 managers. For each team manager, the dataset contains a column that specifies the manager's educational background, named 'ISCED Categorization Manager 1', 'ISCED Categorization Manager 2' .... 'ISCED Categorization Manager 17'. The educational backgrounds are divided into categories which are numbered from 0 to 11.

I want to compute the diversity in educational backgrounds per team. For this, I use the Normalized Gibbs Entropy, which has the following formula:

[Normalised Gibbs Entropy Formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f3qd5.png)
In this formula, Pi is the proportion of the team that has one category of educational background, and N is the team size, which is specified in the column 'Team size 2015'.

I want to write a formula in Python that creates a new column, in which it states the Normalized Gibbs Entropy per row (and thus per team). For each educational category (0-10), the formula should go through the columns 'ISCED Categorization Manager 1' until 'ISCED Categorization Manager 17', compute the proportion of managers in the team that have this categorization, and compute the formula (pi * ln(pi) / ln(N) )

I tried computing this in Excel using Countif functions, but the formula became extremely long and slow. Therefore I want to find a solution in Python.

Hopefully this explanation is clear.

EDIT:

This is some example data:

```
+-------------+-----------+--------------------------------+--------------------------------+--------------------------------+--------------------------------+--------------------------------+--------------------------------+--------------------------------+--------------------------------+--------------------------------+---------------------------------+---------------------------------+---------------------------------+---------------------------------+---------------------------------+---------------------------------+---------------------------------+---------------------------------+
| Team Number | Team Size | ISCED Categorization Manager 1 | ISCED Categorization Manager 2 | ISCED Categorization Manager 3 | ISCED Categorization Manager 4 | ISCED Categorization Manager 5 | ISCED Categorization Manager 6 | ISCED Categorization Manager 7 | ISCED Categorization Manager 8 | ISCED Categorization Manager 9 | ISCED Categorization Manager 10 | ISCED Categorization Manager 11 | ISCED Categorization Manager 12 | ISCED Categorization Manager 13 | ISCED Categorization Manager 14 | ISCED Categorization Manager 15 | ISCED Categorization Manager 16 | ISCED Categorization Manager 17 |
+-------------+-----------+--------------------------------+--------------------------------+--------------------------------+--------------------------------+--------------------------------+--------------------------------+--------------------------------+--------------------------------+--------------------------------+---------------------------------+---------------------------------+---------------------------------+---------------------------------+---------------------------------+---------------------------------+---------------------------------+---------------------------------+
|           1 |         3 |                              1 |                              5 |                              9 |                                |                                |                                |                                |                                |                                |                                 |                                 |                                 |                                 |                                 |                                 |                                 |                                 |
|           2 |         5 |                              9 |                              9 |                              9 |                              9 |                              9 |                                |                                |                                |                                |                                 |                                 |                                 |                                 |                                 |                                 |                                 |                                 |
|           3 |        17 |                              2 |                              2 |                              4 |                              2 |                              4 |                              4 |                              2 |                              5 |                              5 |                               5 |                               5 |                               5 |                               5 |                               5 |                               5 |                               5 |                               5 |
|           4 |         5 |                              3 |                              3 |                              5 |                              6 |                              5 |                                |                                |                                |                                |                                 |                                 |                                 |                                 |                                 |                                 |                                 |                                 |
+-------------+-----------+--------------------------------+--------------------------------+--------------------------------+--------------------------------+--------------------------------+--------------------------------+--------------------------------+--------------------------------+--------------------------------+---------------------------------+---------------------------------+---------------------------------+---------------------------------+---------------------------------+---------------------------------+---------------------------------+---------------------------------+
```

In python, all empty cells are NaN.
For this data, the Normalized Gibbs Entropy output should be:

Team 1: 1

Team 2: 0

Team 3: 0.338.... --> =-1*SUM(((10/17)*LN(10/17)/LN(17)),((4/17)*LN(4/17)/LN(17)),((3/17)*LN(3/17)/LN(17)))

Team 4: 0.6554.... --> =-1*SUM(((2/5)*LN(2/5)/LN(5)),((2/5)*LN(2/5)/LN(5)),((1/5)*LN(1/5)/LN(5)))

Comment: Can you add some example data and the expected result? Then I can help

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer! I added some example data @TomMcLean

Comment: Please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) (especially regarding the pictures).

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to stack overflow. I tried to edit the example data so that it fits the guidelines